# PHP Imagick after rotateImage update last modified

Tags: php, imagick

I have a site where users can upload images. Sometimes these images needs to be rotated.

Using Imagicks rotateImage function is no problem but the image might already be cached by other users on the site. Can I update the image files last modified header?

My rotate script:

```
    $imagick = new Imagick(); 
    $imagick->readImage("path-to-image"); 
    $imagick->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel(), 90); 
    $imagick->writeImage(path-to-image);
    print $imagick->getImage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once rotated serve the image with the expire date in the past

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2007 05:00:00 GMT");
```